How to retain the blend mode along with the export?
Blend and Texture are not intact on export
I am trying to export my wireframe globe model in blender and i am using image texture and blend mode: alpha blend in my model to render the globe, but when i try to export the model the texture and blendmode is not intact.

I tried exporting the model in .fbx and .gltf formats, but neither had the texture and blendmode intact. Is there a way to do it?
I am trying to use this model in my Threejs project, so is there any alternative way to do it too?

Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

Thank you for letting me know

Note that the "Blend Mode: Alpha Mode" setting is supported by the glTF exporter, but some nodes (color ramp, mix shader) are not. In general your material must be set up according to the docs at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html in order to export to glTF. Import to three.js should work once the glTF file is correctly exported.
